# Maximum likelihood calculation : error with function in the sum(..) function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate a maximum likelihood with Matlab.

So I write a file function call `sigmalos.m` (with the function `sigmalos(x,R,br,rh)`) where x is a matrix with 2 real numbers `[x(1),x(2)]`enter code here and R,br,rh just 3 real numbers.

Then, I want to use **"fminsearch" to obtain x(1) and x(2)**, but I am not at this point right now.

My problem is that I have 47 data points.
My data is a matrix 47*3 call input. I need the first column in my calculation.

So i need to do something like :
`sum(sigmalos(x,input(1:47,1),br,rh)` and then apply `fminsearch on x in this sum()`...

Problem, I cant do that :

- Error using sigmalos
- Too many input arguments.

Do you have any suggestion ? Thanks !

Comment: Why does the title of your question suggest that this has to do with `sum` when the error itself indicates that the issue is with `sigmalos`? You have a lot of text and explanation that seems irrelevant to someone trying to help. Can you even call the `sigmalos(x,input(1:47,1),br,rh)` on it's own? Have you defined four inputs in the function definition for `sigmalos`? The issue seems to be in that file, so if you can't find it there yourself, you'll need to be more specific and provide code.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not really clear...
I can call sigmalos(x,input(1,1,br,rh) without any problem. But i don't understand how to call sum() on the sigmalos function from input(1,1) to input (47,1).

Comment: If you have written sigmalos yourself, why don't you compute the sum inside it, and then just return this single output?